# my next view is not displayed when i selected index in tableview & after that i want to go in next view

Tags: iphone

```
#import "PantryLocator.h"
#import "RootViewController.h"
#import "CustomView.h"
#import "PantriesViewController.h"
#import "LafoodbankAppDelegate.h"

@implementation PantryLocator

@synthesize mymapView , activityIndicator , indexRow , cityName , customButton;

// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [self setCityName];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(void)setCityName
{
    app5 = (LafoodbankAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    pantryDetail = [app5.cities objectAtIndex:indexRow];

    cityName.frame = CGRectMake(80, 240, 150, 15);

    [cityName setTitle:pantryDetail.cityName forState:UIControlStateNormal];


    //[self setCustomButton];
}

/*-(void)setCustomButton
{
    //To set custom button
    customButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [customButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"go-button-green.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [customButton addTarget:self action:@selector(goOnPantriesViewController:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [customButton setFrame:CGRectMake(272, 239, 20, 21)];
    [self.view addSubview:customButton];
}*/

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    [textField release];
    return YES;
}

-(IBAction)backHome:(id)sender
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

-(IBAction)selectCity:(id)sender
{

    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] init];
    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
    actionSheet.frame = CGRectMake(0,225,320,200);
    actionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent;

    CustomView *myView = [[CustomView alloc]initWithNibName:@"CustomView" bundle:nil];
    [actionSheet addSubview:myView.view];
    [actionSheet release];

    //myView.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320,100);
    //[myView release];
    /*UIPickerView *pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 40, 0, 0)];
    pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    pickerView.delegate = self;
    pickerView.dataSource = self;

    [actionSheet addSubview:pickerView];
    [pickerView release];

    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
    [actionSheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 485)];
    //[actionSheet release];*/
}

-(IBAction)parsingCity:(id)sender
{
    //Reading file from URL
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"http://www.lafoodbank.org/pantry-xml.aspx?city=all"];
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url];

    //Parsing
    parser = [[PantryParser alloc]init];
    [parser parseXML:data];
    [data release];
}

-(IBAction)goOnPantriesViewController:(id)sender
{
    PantriesViewController *pantriesViewController = [[PantriesViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"PantriesViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:pantriesViewController animated:YES];
    [pantriesViewController release];
}

-(IBAction)goToDesignsite:(id)sender
{
    DesignWebView *designWebView = [[DesignWebView alloc]initWithNibName:@"DesignWebView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:designWebView animated:YES];
    [designWebView release];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning 
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload 
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (void)dealloc 
{
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

In above code i am confused that i am not go to next view when i select a particular city in setCityName so please give me solution.....

Comment: Can u describe your problem in detail ? so that i can gave u the more proper solution....

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] init];
```

Try This.

```
    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Your Title" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

hi friend 
 Go to your nib file and add method to your button first